# Exception while trying to sign an ANDROID app - "java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes"

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, android-app-signing

I am relatively new to android development and I was trying to sign the apk file, but I get an exception with the message - "java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes".

After going through various forums, I understood that it could be because of META-INF/msftsig.sf file that was included with external msft dependency. I am not able to find an answer on how to exclude this files in an ANDROID project. Any help on this is really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I finally resolved my issue.

Earlier I was trying to exclude the SF files in  packagingOptions(build.gradle file) using regular expression like below

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
}
```

For some reason this didn't work and when I changed to give the complete file name it worked. example below:

```
    packagingOptions {
             exclude 'META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF'
        exclude 'META_INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
    }
```